# the names of (plural) or the name of (plural)

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering which option is correct:

1) we will have **the name** of the people who play on this team.

2) we will have **the names** of the people who play on this team.

Should 'name' be plural or singular?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever visited [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)? It's a great site for more fundamental English questions. Please take their [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) to see if this question (and others you might have) would be a good fit there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"We will have the names of" is correct, as you are showing multiple people, and as such, it is plural.